# How to check user has given an valid upi id to make a payout in razorpay

Tags: reactjs, mern, razorpay, upi

In my react web application i need to proceed an payout to my customer. I will get the upi id of the user from the input and process the transaction. Now i had a doubt what if the user gives me an wrong upi id . Is there any way to check the upi id is valid or not in MERN stack development.

Answer (score 0):

Razorpay checkout will validate the UPI request before letting the user proceed with payment.
If you are using Razorpay,you don't need to handle it at your side.

Comment: what will be the response from razorpayX if it is an invalid upi .i cant find it in the docs

Comment: @MohanRaj why not raise a ticket here. https://razorpay.com/support/